# Como puedo juntar mis resultados en una sola fila de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Actualmente tengo una consulta que me arroja como resultado lo siguiente:

[image]

Lo que requiero es que los resultados de mayo no aparezcan abajo sino que se pongan al lado, en pocas palabras es subir esos nuevos resultados arriba que serian los de mayo para que Geos tenga abril y mayo juntos, Indirectos igual y el resto de clases de coste. Ya intente con el group by pero me dejo la misma estructura en mi resultado

Codigo Actual:

```
select [Clase de Coste],isnull([Enero],0) as Enero,isnull([Febrero],0) as Febrero,isnull([Marzo],0) as Marzo, isnull([Abril],0) as Abril, isnull([Mayo],0) as Mayo,ISNULL([Junio],0) as Junio,isnull([Julio],0) as Julio,isnull([Agosto],0) as Agosto,isnull([Septiembre],0) as Septiembre,isnull([Octubre],0) as Octubre,isnull([Noviembre],0) as Noviembre,isnull([Diciembre],0) as Diciembre from (
select [Clase de Coste],[Importe Banco], case MONTH([Fecha de Corte])
when 1 then 'Enero' when 2 then 'Febrero' when 3 then 'Marzo' when 4 then 'Abril' when 5 then 'Mayo'
when 6 then 'Junio' when 7 then 'Julio' when 8 then 'Agosto' when 9 then 'Septiembre' when 10 then 'Octubre' when 11 then 'Noviembre'
when 12 then 'Diciembre' else 'NULL' end as Mes,MONTH([Fecha de Corte]) as NumeroMes
from PartidasGasto_WS as partidas  
where ([Clase de Coste] is not null) and ([Fecha de Corte] is not null)
group by [Clase de Coste],[Importe Banco],[Fecha de Corte]
)s
PIVOT (SUM([Importe Banco]) FOR Mes IN ([Enero],[Febrero],[Marzo],[Abril],[Mayo],[Junio],[Julio],[Agosto],[Septiembre],[Octubre],[Noviembre],[Diciembre])) as p
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es la salida que esperas. Agrega un texto (no imagen) de la salida que esperas y también los datos de entrada para producir esa salida. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo te falta agregar SUM a cada mes...:

```html
select [Clase de Coste],
  SUM(isnull([Enero],0))  as Enero,  
  SUM(isnull([Febrero],0)) as Febrero,
  SUM(Isnull([Marzo],0)) as Marzo, 
  SUM(Isnull([Abril],0)) as Abril, 
  SUM(Isnull([Mayo],0)) as Mayo,
  SUM(ISNULL([Junio],0)) as Junio,
  SUM(Isnull([Julio],0)) as Julio,
  SUM(Isnull([Agosto],0)) as Agosto,
  SUM(Isnull([Septiembre],0)) as Septiembre,
  SUM(Isnull([Octubre],0)) as Octubre,
  SUM(Isnull([Noviembre],0)) as Noviembre,
  SUM(Isnull([Diciembre],0)) as Diciembre 
from (
  
  
  select [Clase de Coste],[Importe Banco], case MONTH([Fecha de Corte])
    when 1 then 'Enero' 
    when 2 then 'Febrero' 
    when 3 then 'Marzo' 
    when 4 then 'Abril' 
    when 5 then 'Mayo'
    when 6 then 'Junio' 
    when 7 then 'Julio' 
    when 8 then 'Agosto' 
    when 9 then 'Septiembre' 
    when 10 then 'Octubre' 
    when 11 then 'Noviembre'
    when 12 then 'Diciembre' 
    else 'NULL' end as Mes, MONTH([Fecha de Corte]) as NumeroMes
  from
  (
       select  'CROSS    '  [Clase de Coste]  ,324482.21   [Importe Banco]  ,  '2019-01-16'  [Fecha de Corte]
   union all select  'ELAB         '        ,436822.00     , '2019-01-17'
   union all select  'ESTRUCTURA   '        ,5527937.32     , '2019-01-18'
   union all select  'FSW          '        ,1726950.57     , '2019-01-19'
   union all select  'GEOS         '        ,4880460.72     , '2019-04-20'
   union all select  'INDIRECTOS   '        ,5282523.59     , '2019-04-21'
   union all select  'Poc OTROS    '        ,6248133.38     , '2019-04-22'
   union all select  'STAFFING     '        ,364909.68     , '2019-04-23'
   union all select  'TYM          '        ,7977820.79     , '2019-04-21'
   union all select  'Vaticos      '        ,6723419.84     , '2019-04-22'
   union all select  'Estrucuturas '        ,2253616.21     , '2019-04-23'
   union all select  'GEOS         '        ,3866027.23     , '2019-04-24'
   union all select  'Ppc otres    '        ,1031076.19     , '2019-04-25'
   union all select  'STAFFING     '        ,5740257.65     , '2019-04-26'
   union all select  'GEOS         '        ,4880460.72     , '2019-05-22'
   union all select  'Poc OTROS    '        ,6248133.38     , '2019-05-24'
   union all select  'STAFFING     '        ,364909.68     , '2019-05-25'
   union all select  'TYM          '        ,7977820.79     , '2019-05-25'
  )t
)s
PIVOT (SUM([Importe Banco]) 
FOR Mes IN ([Enero],[Febrero],[Marzo],[Abril],[Mayo],[Junio],[Julio],[Agosto],[Septiembre],[Octubre],[Noviembre],[Diciembre])) as p 
group by [Clase de Coste]
```